# how to clear outbox with vba in outlook, still got one outgoing email

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to "send" a message to specific recipient but do not want to deliver. The message is in the outbox but I want to delete it immediately. When I use the command delete it says it was deleted before sending. I do not want popups and also there is an alert when exiting Outlook that there are still unsent messages. How to clear outbox?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim deletedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim entryID As String

Set outApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set deletedFolder  =outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)

If item.To = "example@mail.com" Then
    item.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("y", 99999, Now)
End If

Set deletedFolder =    outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)

If deletedFolder.Items.Count >= 0 Then
    For i = 1 To deletedFolder.Items.Count
        deletedFolder.Items(1).Delete
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outbook folder contains yet unsent messages. It is definitely not the right time and place for deleting items because they were not sent. Instead, I'd suggest handling the ItemSend event and adding a user property (i.e. marker which can tell you later whether you need to delete that message or not), see UserProperties property of the MailItem class for more information. For example:

```
 Set myUserProperty = myItem.UserProperties _ 
 .Add("YourDetails", olText) 
 myUserProperty.Value = "Delete"
```

Then in the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event handler of the Sent Items folder you can check out the user defined property value and delete the sent message if required. Be aware, the Sent Items folder is set as a target folder by default for sent items. But you can set a custom folder programmatically, see the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868473(v=office.15).aspx) property - a Folder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent.

Comment: thank you for an idea, but I am not that good coder I was just editing some snippets, I will try to understand that and test it but anyway, do you know some simple way to perform a Send but do not deliver the message, thats why I used a delay but now its stucked in outbox. I guess that if there would be an outbox clear command only for a specific recipient then it would be ok because there are no more than one items in outbox anyway.

Comment: You can set the Cancel parameter to true (see the passed to the ItemSend event handler parameter). Thus, your email will not be sent.

Comment: that might be good but where do I place the cancel command do I need to use the initialize command

`codePublic WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application
 Public Sub Initialize_handler()
 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim prompt As String
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
  Cancel = True
 End If
End Sub`

Comment: well the cancel command will not perform a send when clicking the send button.. but I want to perform the send and then cancel the message/delete it from outgoing